# CASE WHEN query not returning expected results

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to get data from the wp_usermeta table of the Wordpress database.

For those who aren't familliar with it, the structure is as follows:

```
umeta_id | user_id | meta_key | meta_value
1        | 1       | role     | admin
2        | 1       | lat      | 12.34456
3        | 1       | lng      | 9.392933
4        | 2       | role     | user
5        | 2       | lat      | 8.694840
6        | 2       | lng      | 29.32930
7        | 3       | role     | subscriber
8        | 3       | lat      | 32.32323
9        | 3       | lng      | 3.222222
10       | 3       | some key | some value
... and so on
```

Now I've got an entry with latitude and longitude coordinates inside the table, which are defined by the meta_key being "lat" or "long" and the meta_value being the coordinates.

I'd like to get each user with their lat and long coords, like this:

```
user_id | lat      | lng
1       | 12.34456 | 9.392933
2       | 8.694840 | 29.32930
3       | 32.32323 | 3.222222
```

For that I am currently using this query:

```
SELECT umeta.user_id,
max(CASE WHEN umeta.meta_key = "lat" THEN umeta.meta_value END) AS lat,
max(CASE WHEN umeta.meta_key = "lng" THEN umeta.meta_value END) AS lng
FROM wp_usermeta umeta
```

Which only gives me:

```
user_id | lat      | lng
1       | 12.34456 | 9.392933
```

Do you guys have any idea what I am doing wrong?
Help really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to also group by the user id to make the pivot query work as expected:

```
SELECT umeta.user_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN umeta.meta_key = "lat" THEN umeta.meta_value ELSE 0 END) AS lat,
       MAX(CASE WHEN umeta.meta_key = "lng" THEN umeta.meta_value ELSE 0 END) AS lng
FROM wp_usermeta umeta
GROUP BY umeta.user_id
```

I included an explicit `ELSE` condition setting a 0 value, although you might not need this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT umeta.user_id,
       max(CASE WHEN umeta.meta_key = "lat" THEN umeta.meta_value END) AS lat,
       max(CASE WHEN umeta.meta_key = "lng" THEN umeta.meta_value END) AS lng
FROM wp_usermeta umeta
GROUP BY umeta.user_id
```

Without a `GROUP BY` clause, the query that contains an aggregate function in the `SELECT` clause, returns *always* one record.